# Redshift - How to update aging column when doing an incremental update of the table

Tags: amazon-redshift, incremental-build

I have a table that updates incrementally once every day. Table has about 10 million records but I update only rows that were created or updated in the last 24 hours. This runs perfectly fine however I have a problem with one of the columns that calculates the aging of each sale (record) that is calculated based on time when the record was created and compares it against the latest data run time. I would like to know how could I have just this column update for each of the 10 million rows each time the table updates incrementally.

I am using Amazon Redshift as the DB.

Thanks..

Comment: Redshift doesnt allow updates to single columns in the way you describe. You can write `UPDATE x SET y = z WHERE whatever` but the entire row is still tombstoned (soft delete) and a new record written to the dirty portion of the file structure. This is only tidied up during a VACUUM.  You're probably better off with a VIEW that computes the age at query time.

Comment: Agreed. There is no reason to store an `age` column in a database. Rather, a `SELECT` can simply calculate the difference between the date in a `Created` column and the current date (or the last load date if it is accessible somewhere).